# poker expectation clarification

Tags: game-theory, poker

I ran across a passage in "The Mathematics of Poker" explaining bluffing strategy. Here is a paraphrased version.

Two players are playing heads-up ($1$ vs $1$) poker. They're on the final betting street (the river; so all $5$ community cards have been revealed). Player A has the winning hand $20\%$ of the time, and has the losing hand $80\%$ of the time. Both players are aware of these $20/80$ probabilities. For each given hand, Player A can see the cards of both players cards, and so knows who has the winning hand. The pot has $4$ dollars in it. Player A is first to act.

If A checks, B will never bet because A will know whether they have the winning hand or not in response and will raise / fold accordingly. So we know that A will not check the winning hands in order to try and milk more value out of them. But if A bets if and only if they have the winning hand, B will always fold. So, A will choose some $x$% of hands to bluff.

A's selection of $x$ is their strategy. We want to find the best $x$.

B loses $1$ dollar for calling when A has the winning hand, and B wins $(4 \text{ in the pot } + 1 \text{ bluff}) = 5$ dollars when A bluffs. B's calling strategy only applies when A bets, so the probability values below are conditional on A betting. The expectation of B's hand if he calls is:

$$
\begin{align}
E(B ,\text{ call}) &= P(\text{A has winning hand})(-1) + P(\text{A bluffs})(5) \\ 
&= (0.2)(-1) + (x)(5)\\ 
&= 5x - 0.2
\end{align}
$$

If B folds, his expectation is simply $0$, so $E(B ,\text{ fold}) = 0$

If A bluffs often B should call all the time. If A bluffs rarely, B should never call. Here is a graphical representation:

[image]

Based on this, the author claims that B should call when $x>0.04$, and fold when $x < 0.04$, which is obviously true.

But what about A? This question was initially about A's strategy, namely deciding $x$. I am confused about why should A bluff with a probability of $4\%$. Whether A bluffs $4\%$ of the time or $0\%$ of the time, B's EV is $0$. Within this range of $x$, B's strategy does not change and the EV does not exceed $0$. As a result, why would it matter how often A bluffs so long as $x \leq 0.04$?

Comment: There's a lot of jargon in this (never heard the term "nuts" in this context), and it is quite long.  It also seems that you started with $y$ and then switched to $x$ with no explanation, but the whole thing is confusing so perhaps I am misreading.  I suggest editing it for clarity and for brevity.

Comment: @lulu I made the question shorter, simpler, and removed the x/y mistake. Thank you for that catch

Comment: To your question:  It's not as if $A$ announces their bluffing strategy.  If they did, $B's$ move would be obvious, but they don't.  $B$ has to infer that from history and that's problematic (as $A$ is aware of the history and therefore is aware of $B's$ likely response to it).  The match would appear to suggest that $A$ should bluff "about" $4\%$ of the time, going up and down from there according to $B's$ responses.

Comment: But, of course, it's all pretty stripped down.  In reality, the probability of winning is a lot more complicated than this.  In a $2$ player game, there are lots of hands that win a lot of the time, but far from always.

Comment: @lulu yeah, that makes sense. But in a game where strategies were announced, B would be would be equally content with 4% and 2% and A would be impartial to this choice, right?

Comment: That's right.  This just gives a clear(er) mathematical basis for how $A,B$ should be thinking about a dynamic strategy.  If $A$ has been bluffing around $3.5\%$ of the time, $B$ should stop calling, in which case $A$ can go up to $5\%$ of the time (or whatever) for a while, confident that $B$ won't call.  At least until $B$ catches on.